# LINQ context SubmitChanges

Tags: linq, submitchanges

Regarding the SubmitChanges order (Insert, Update, Delete), is there a way to change that order? I need to have the Deletes executed first, any updates, then any new inserts. I have a datagrid where the user can do all add, changes and updates and submit. Since each grid row must have a unique item chosen in it (via a dropdown), it's possible for the the user to delete the row, then try to utilize the deleted dropdown item in a new row, then try to update all changes and have the update fail (since the item the user wants to delete actually still exists in the database because the submit is doing the inserts first). Is there a setting where I can control the automatic update order or do I have to manually do the updates myself?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but you could consider the following. First, get the `ChangeSet` using [`DataContext.ChangeSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx). Then, run through the `ChangeSet.Deletes` calling `Table<T>.DeleteOnSubmit` on a new instance of your `DataContext`. Rinse repeat for the `ChangeSet.Updates` and the `ChangeSet.Inserts`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to do this. You would have to process the changes in the order you want, and call SubmitChanges() after each insert, update or delete. If you want the whole thing within the scope of a transaction, use the TransactionScope object.